# Laravel, convert to uuid text from uuid binary upon creating model

Tags: php, laravel

Currently, I'm using [spatie uuid](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-binary-uuid) package. The problem is, it automatically create a uuid binary(16) instead of uuid text upon creating a new row of data. I wanted to insert the text version of the uuid. Is it possible to do that?

**Model**

```
use HasBinaryUuid;
protected $table = 'furnitures';
protected $guarded = [];

public $incrementing = false;

public function getKeyName()
{
    return 'id';
}
```

**Controller (store)**

```
return Furniture::create([
        'name' => $request['name'],
        'code' => $request['code'],
]); //this automatically generate uuid binary(16) id
```

Comment: Are you aware that text based uuid as very slow comapred to binary uuid if you wish to search something using uuid?

Comment: Yes, i'm aware of the performance differences. But i'm still wanted to know how to solve my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library you are using is optimizing the UUID by storing it as binary. Using the same library to store it as text would be working against its purpose. There shouldn't be any reason for you to store it as text because the library is making all the conversions for you.

For example, if you wanted to use the UUID in a URL or JSON, the library can convert from binary to text for you.

```
$model = MyModel::create();
dump($model->uuid_text); // "6dae40fa-cae0-11e7-80b6-8c85901eed2e"
```

Have a look at the [documentation](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-binary-uuid#getting-a-human-readable-uuid) for more examples.

There are also other UUID libraries available for Laravel, that doesn't use a binary version.

1. [Ramsey UUID](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid)
2. [Webpatser UUID](https://github.com/webpatser/laravel-uuid)
3. [EmadAdly UUID](https://github.com/EmadAdly/laravel-uuid)

Answer (score 0):

I founded a way to solve this by using this code `Mymodel::generateUuid(true)` which returns uuid text version. But i'm not sure this is the best way to do it. Any other ideas are welcome to post.

```
return Furniture::create([
    'id' => Furniture::generateUuid(true),
    'name' => $request['name'],
    'code' => $request['code'],
]);
```